# Symlink/link in project directory

Tags: r, symlink, symlink-traversal

I've got a project directory that's become a bit of a mess, and I'm trying to tidy it up into a structure something like this:

```
/data
    /raw
    /cleaning_scripts
/analysis
...
```

Some of the raw data is kept in a directory outside the project directory, and I'd like to keep my project neat and tidy by putting a link to the directory containing the external data in the `/raw` directory. But R doesn't let me do something like

```
read.csv("data/raw/my_link/my_data.csv")
```

Is there a way to get around this, ideally one that won't involve jumping through so many hoops that my collaborators get confused? Or a better practice for situating the data that would obviate the need to read the link the way I am?

This is on a windows machine, by the way, and the project folder is being shared through a remote git repo.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the post. For these things, I usually go with the less sophisticated method of saving explicit paths at the top of my scripts. Also adding comments to each.